Getting bounding box issue
This code has been written on this video  and i don't know why its not working, i realized that for this code, i got error.
This part of code:
train_dataset = SAMDataset(dataset=dataset, processor=processor)
example = train_dataset[0]
for k,v in example.items():
  print(k,v.shape)

The Error:
raise ValueError(f"Unsupported number of image dimensions: {image.ndim}")
ValueError: Unsupported number of image dimensions: 2
Also, We're going to see this line of code and the same error:
Code:
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, drop_last=False)
batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))
# for k, v in batch.items():
#     print(k, v.shape)

Full Code:
!pip install numpy
!pip install segment-anything
!pip install transformers
!pip install datasets
!pip install patchify
!pip install matplotlib
!pip install tifffile
!pip install pillow
!pip install torch
!pip install datasets

from patchify import patchify
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import datasets as ds
import tifffile
from transformers import SamProcessor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader



large_images = tifffile.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/MitochondriaImage/training.tif")
large_masks = tifffile.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/MitochondriaImage/training_groundtruth.tif")

patch_size = 256
step = 256

all_img_patches = []
for img in range(large_images.shape[0]):
    large_image = large_images[img]
    patches_img = patchify(large_image, (patch_size, patch_size), step=step)  # No overlap

    # For each patch, extracts the patch data and assigns it to single_patch_img
    for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
            single_patch_img = patches_img[i, j, :, :]
            all_img_patches.append(single_patch_img)

images = np.array(all_img_patches)

# Same for masks
all_mask_patches = []
for img in range(large_masks.shape[0]):
    large_mask = large_masks[img]
    patches_mask = patchify(large_mask, (patch_size, patch_size), step=step)

    for i in range(patches_mask.shape[0]):
        for j in range(patches_mask.shape[1]):
            single_patch_mask = patches_mask[i, j, :, :]
            single_patch_mask = (single_patch_mask / 255.).astype(np.uint8)
            all_mask_patches.append(single_patch_mask)

masks = np.array(all_mask_patches)

# print(images.shape)
# print(masks.shape)

valid_indices = [i for i, mask in enumerate(masks) if mask.max() != 0]
filtered_images = images[valid_indices]
filtered_masks = masks[valid_indices]

dataset_dict = {
    'image': [Image.fromarray(img) for img in filtered_images],
    'label': [Image.fromarray(mask) for mask in filtered_masks],
}

dataset = ds.Dataset.from_dict(dataset_dict)

# Making sure out images and masks (labels) are loading appropriately

img_num = random.randint(0, filtered_images.shape[0] - 1)
example_image = dataset[img_num]["image"]
example_mask = dataset[img_num]["label"]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))

# Plot the first image on the left
axes[0].imshow(np.array(example_image), cmap='gray')  # Assuming the first image is grayscale
axes[0].set_title("Image")

# Plot the second image on the right
axes[1].imshow(example_mask, cmap='gray')  # Assuming the second image is grayscale
axes[1].set_title("Mask")

# Hide axis ticks and labels
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])


# Display the images side by side
plt.show()



def get_bounding_box(ground_truth_map):
    """
    Bounding box is easy to extract with this mask, we lock to somewhere that ground truth mask (a binary mask) is not equal to zero.
    """
    # Get bounding box from mask
    y_indices, x_indices = np.where(ground_truth_map > 0)
    x_min, x_max = np.min(x_indices), np.max(x_indices)
    y_min, y_max = np.min(y_indices), np.max(y_indices)
    # Add perturbation to bounding box coordinates
    H, W = ground_truth_map.shape
    x_min = max(0, x_min - np.random.randint(0, 20))
    x_max = min(W, x_max + np.random.randint(0, 20))
    y_min = max(0, y_min - np.random.randint(0, 20))
    y_max = min(H, y_max + np.random.randint(0, 20))
    bbox = [x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max]

    return bbox


class SAMDataset(Dataset):
  """
  This class is used to create a dataset that serves input images and masks.
  It takes a dataset and a processor as input and overrides the __len__ and __getitem__ methods of the Dataset class.
  """
  def __init__(self, dataset, processor):
    self.dataset = dataset
    self.processor = processor

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.dataset)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    item = self.dataset[idx]
    image = item["image"]
    ground_truth_mask = np.array(item["label"])

    # get bounding box prompt
    prompt = get_bounding_box(ground_truth_mask)

    # prepare image and prompt for the model
    inputs = self.processor(image, input_boxes=[[prompt]], return_tensors="pt")

    # remove batch dimension which the processor adds by default
    inputs = {k:v.squeeze(0) for k,v in inputs.items()}

    # add ground truth segmentation
    inputs["ground_truth_mask"] = ground_truth_mask

    return inputs


processor = SamProcessor.from_pretrained("facebook/sam-vit-base")
train_dataset = SAMDataset(dataset=dataset, processor=processor)

# ERROR
# example = train_dataset[0]
# for k,v in example.items():
#   print(k,v.shape)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, drop_last=False)

# ERROR
# batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))



I expected it to output like this after running the Code section below
train_dataset = SAMDataset(dataset=dataset, processor=processor)
example = train_dataset[0]
for k,v in example.items():
  print(k,v.shape)

output
but it gave me the ERROR that i mentioned.
